# How to dynamically create named classes in Coffeescript without using eval?

Tags: coffeescript

I want to be able to write:

`generate 'Cat', 'meow'`

and define the `generate` function in such a way that it produces:

```
class Cat
  meow: ->
    @.__proto__.constructor.name + ' says meow.'
```

so that I can write:

```
garfield = new Cat
garfield.meow() # "Cat says meow"
```

Comment: I'm confused by your example. You want `generate 'Cat', 'meow'` to generate code that incorporates neither `"Cat"` nor `"meow"`?

Comment: I'm sorry, I've corrected the example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind polluting your global namespace, I actually got this snippet running in the 'try coffeescript' runner at the [CoffeeScript site](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/):

```
root = exports ? window
alert = alert or console.log

gen = (clsname, val) ->
  root[clsname] = class
    meow: => "#{clsname} says #{val}"

gen 'Cat', 'meow'
g = new root.Cat
alert g.meow()

gen 'Dog', 'woff'
d = new root.Dog
alert d.meow()
```

Not 100% what you asked for, but it's almost what you wanted, isn't it?

**Edit:** Actually, the first script only worked in the browser, not the (`Node.js`-based) CLI, corrected the script.

If you know you'll only live in the browser, you can loose `root.Cat` and only say `Cat`, but if you want Node.js *and* browser compat, you'll have to live with `root.*`

**Edit 2:** It's generally a better idea to return the class from the generating function rather than magically putting it in a namespace. It's also possible to make the method names dynamic. With some inspiration from @Loren, the asker (notice how it doesn't need to refer the global object anymore):

```
alert = alert or console.log

gen = (clsname, val) ->
  C = class
  C.prototype[val] = -> "#{clsname} says #{val}"
  C

Cat = gen 'Cat', 'meow'
console.log Cat
g = new Cat
alert g.meow()

Dog = gen 'Dog', 'woff'
d = new Dog
alert d.woff()
```

Comment: The most recent version (Cat = gen ...) now doesn't run in the coffeescript test page. I'm getting "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation." Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If by "named class" you mean "a class with a named function," what you're asking for isn't possible—in CoffeeScript or JavaScript. Without `eval`, there's no way to create the equivalent of `function FuncName() {...}`. You can only use the `__proto__.constructor.name` property on functions defined with that syntax.

The `class` syntax is the only way of creating named functions in CoffeeScript, for reasons explained in the [FAQ](http://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/wiki/faq).